How update the dateformat in a table
i have a table with 10000 dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD, column is varchar2.
how can i update them to the format DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI ?
The application in apex has the application date format DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI
i have the error ORA-01843: not a valid month because the dateformates are not the same.

NEVER store a date as a string data-type; always use the most appropriate format, which for a date is a DATE data-type.
For example, if you have the sample data:
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name)
SELECT '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1999-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2024-04-29' FROM DUAL;

Then you can create a second column and populate it using:
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name_dt DATE;

UPDATE table_name
SET column_name_dt = TO_DATE(column_name, 'YYYY-MM-DD');

Then verify that the data is correct and drop the first column and rename:
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name;

ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN column_name_dt TO column_name;

Then, the table contains:
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI';

SELECT * FROM table_name;




COLUMN_NAME




01-JAN-1970 00:00


31-DEC-1999 00:00


29-APR-2024 00:00



When you SELECT from the table in Oracle Apex then it will display all the DATE columns according to the application date format; so having stored your data as a DATE (and not a string) then you can have it automatically formatted into the correct format. If you later want to change how the values are displayed then you can just change the application date format and they will all display in the new format - you never need to modify the underlying data because you are using a DATE data type (and not a pre-formatted string).
fiddle

oh yes sure, the data and the database is from a very old application, so i use the old data in a new format in the new application, thankyou.

If you want to update the same column in VARCHAR2 date type you can do:
UPDATE tablename
SET    col_name = to_char(to_date(col_name, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')

but if you get ORA-01843 error, you can find invalid monthes by the following query:
SELECT * 
FROM   table_name
WHERE  substr (col_name, 6, 2) NOT IN ('01', '02, '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12')

and then you should correct these records.
If it is possoble for you, it is better to change the data type to DATE.
